# Entering hibernate mode after delay upon going to sleep mode doesn't work when using power supply

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, power, hibernate

I've successfully set the MAC to enter hibernate mode after 1 minute delay upon going to sleep mode but it works only on battery power. When using power supply, the computer stays in sleep mode after 1 minute. How to achieve the same results using power supply?

commands I've used:

```
sudo pmset -a destroyfvkeyonstandby 1
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3
sudo pmset -a standbydelay 60
```

pmset -g gives me these results:

```
standbydelay         60
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 tcpkeepalive         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

I am using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5 on MacBook Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh maybe you should also set autopoweroffdelay to 60.

According to Apple's KB (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201635), it said: "OS X Mountain Lion v10.8.2 supplemental update 2.0 introduced a feature that lets your Mac enter safe sleep after four hours of being connected to AC power."

So it's clear now:

"standby" only takes effect when the computer using BATTERY.

"autopoweroff" only takes effect when the computer is CONNECTED TO AC POWER.

So you should also use this command:

```
sudo pmset -a autopoweroffdelay 60
```

It should work now, hope this helps you.

Comment: Yup that seemed to work. Also for reference it appears that sometime on or after yosemite the default autopoweroffdelay was changed from 14400 (seconds) to 28800.